# Collapse consecutive rows in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have this example `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,5,7,8),b=c(2,3,4,6,8,9))
```

And I'd like to collapse all rows `i` whose `b` column value is equal to `a` column value at their subsequent row (`i+1`) such that in the collapsed row they their `a` column will be that of row `i` and their `b` column will be that of row `i+1`. This has to be done as long as there are no consecutive rows that meet this condition.

For the example `df` rows 1-3 are to be collapsed, row 4 left as is, and then rows 5-6 collapsed, giving:

```
res.df <- data.frame(a = c(1,5,7), b = c(4,6,9))
```

Comment: Are you sure the value in 'b' is correct for res.df

Comment: Yes. Rows 1-3 and 5-6 are collapsed, and row 4 is left as is.

Comment: The condition you mentioned is not giving the expected output

Comment: Perhaps the edited question is clearer?

Comment: You can make the right thing here with just `data.frame(a = df$a[!df$a %in% df$b], b = df$b[!df$b %in% df$a])`, but really I think you're going to have to get creative with `lag` and `rle`.

Comment: You might find useful the "IRanges" package for such things depending on what you're, actually, trying to do; `reduce(IRanges(df$a, df$b), min.gapwidth = 0L`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't overly pretty, but it is vectorised comparing a cutdown version of `df$a` to `df$b`.

```
grps <- rev(cumsum(rev(c(tail(df$a,-1) != head(df$b,-1),TRUE))))
#[1] 3 3 3 2 1 1

cbind(df["a"], b=ave(df$b,grps,FUN=max) )[!duplicated(grps),]

#  a b
#1 1 4
#4 5 6
#5 7 9
```

Breaking it down probably helps explain the first part:

```
tail(df$a,-1) != head(df$b,-1)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
c(tail(df$a,-1) != head(df$b,-1),TRUE)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
rev(c(tail(df$a,-1) != head(df$b,-1),TRUE))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
cumsum(rev(c(tail(df$a,-1) != head(df$b,-1),TRUE)))
#[1] 1 1 2 3 3 3
```